# write some javascript code in response.write when SqlDataSource1_Deleted

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, events, sqldatasource

i have a notification j-query plugin  .. i taste it in my page (working 100%)
but when i want to use it in a event SqlDataSource1_Deleted with the response.write method it does not work

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Deleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Deleted

    Response.Write("<script  type='text/javascript'> showNotification({message: 'This is a sample Success notification', type: 'success' }); </script>")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `Response.Write` in a page, you will be putting the code before the HTML document itself. This means that it will run before jQuery or any plugin is loaded. (And also that it may cause the page to be rendered in quirks mode, which would probably break the entire layout.)

Use the [`RegisterStartupScript` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx) to add a script in the page:

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Deleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Deleted
  Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "notification", "showNotification({message: 'This is a sample Success notification', type: 'success' });", true)
End Sub
```

Comment: yes @Guffa tnkss dudde .. with your help the problem is solved ^^